# jQuery: enable submit when min 1 checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the `"disabled='disabled'` attribute of submit button with `id='bla'` if at least one checkbox with `class='check'` is checked?

If no checkboxes are checked, the disabled attribute should return to the submit button.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT (11-01-2021)** - As pointed out by @Janus Bahs Jacquet, as of jQuery 1.6.1, properties of elements should be manipulated using the `.prop()` method instead of `.attr()` method.

```
$('.check').change(function() {
    if ($('.check:checked').length) {
        $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sub').props('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kjb0fyr8/

---

You just need to check the `length` property of the checked array

```
$('.check').change(function() {
    if ($('.check:checked').length) {
        $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sub').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Here's the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LUnN5/

Comment: +1 (in 11 hours when my vote cap is reset) for getting `:checked` before I thought of it.

Comment: Instead of scanning the DOM again, and instantiating more jQuery objects, using `$('.check:checked').length` you can simply test `this.checked`.

Comment: @Jason You need to scan the DOM because the question asks whether 'any' checkmarks are checked. So even if the one that was clicked is unchecked, there can be others that are checked.

Comment: Ah, checked *array* - I didn't spot that :-)

Comment: This very old (but still valid) answer still appears quite high on Google searches, so you may want to add an update to the effect that the disabled attribute should be toggled using `.prop("disabled", true/false)` since jQuery 1.6.1.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Answered almost a decade ago, I've added your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to all the checkboxes in question, and then on `change()` event, set the `disabled` property based on if any of the checkboxes are checked or not.

```
var checks = $(':checkbox.check');
checks.change(function() {
    $('#bla').attr('disabled', ! checks.filter(':checked').length);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MDjQL/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".check").change(function() {

    var btn = $("#bla");

    if ($(".check").is(":checked")) {

        btn.removeAttr("disabled");

    } else {

        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }

});

$(".check").triggerHandler("change");
```